# how to compare 2 java string array and remove if have same value

Tags: arrays, string, compare, duplicates

i'm having 2 string array,

```
  str1[] = {"a","b","aa","c"}
```

and

```
  str2[] = {"aa","a","b","c","d"}
```

how can i compare and remove value if exist in both string[], expected result, str3[]= {"d"}

thanks in advance

Comment: hi expert, finally i found result for my question, which is     List str3= ListUtils.subtract(Arrays.asList(str1), Arrays.asList(str2));

Comment: Didn't know you are using Apache Commons Library ( ref: ListUtils).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ts1 will have "d" inside it after these operations.

`String str1[] = {"a","b","aa","c"};

String str2[] = {"aa","a","b","c","d"};

TreeSet ts1 = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(str2));

ts1.removeAll(Arrays.asList(str1));`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the arrays to a list and add them to a set which will automatically remove duplicates. Use the toArray() method of Set interface to get the elements as an Array.

```
    String[] str1 = {"a","b","aa","c"};
    String[] str2 = {"aa","a","b","c","d"};

    Set set = new HashSet();
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(str1));//add first array to set, removes duplicates
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(str2));//add second array to set, removes duplicates
    String[] str3 = (String[])set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);//convert back to array
```